# String encryption in editext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have got an EditText in my Android app where you can type in some text. What I want to do is change only first character to another one (some kind of enciphering). Therefore I first have to read every single character.

How can I do that?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.answer);
ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.answer);
String s=ed1.getText().toString();
abc(s);


}
public void abc(String s){
    //get your string
    String str = s;
    //turn it into an array of chars
    char[] strChars = str .toCharArray();
    //set array at position 1 to an x
    strChars[1] = 'x';
     str = String.valueOf(strChars);
     ed1.setText(str);
```

}

Comment: What code do you currently have? We help with issues, not tell you how to do it without you showing what you have tried.

Comment: I am trying to use inputfilter bt it is replacing entire string with the specified character

Comment: here is the code
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            return "$";
         }
        return null;
    }
};

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rg);
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {filter});

Comment: Your over thinking this... hold on

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
    //get your string
    String str = "whatevertextyouwanthere";
    //turn it into an array of chars
    char[] strChars = str .toCharArray();
    //set array at position 1 to an x
    //Check to make sure the length is above -
    if (str.length() != 0)
{
    //Check that we have a value of some sorts in the char array
    if (strChars[0] != ''
{
    //replace the char at place 0 with X
    strChars[0] = 'x';//this might need to be 1
}
}
    //turn the array back into a string
    str = String.valueOf(strChars);
```

Ideally you should have this within a function for ease of use and re-usability. It should return whatever the value of str is.

Post this in your onCreate:

```
ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

          public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            abc(ed1.getText().toString()); 

          }

          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
       });
    }
```

The above was just some code I wrote really quickly but should do what you need it to do. You need to have a listener watching for changes to the edit text.

Comment: (strChars[0] != '') now this line is showing error invalid character constant

Comment: delete that check, its not really needed